# How could I create magento 2 code sniffs ruleset.xml or does someone have it?

Tags: magento2, coding-standards

We developed a module for Magento 2 and we would like the coding standards to match magento 2 coding standard( no warnings or errors ).

Magento 2 has some additional standards that it runs through once you submit a module, we would like that ruleset.xml
We are already using PSR2.

By the way this slightly breaks the rules of StackExchange, but I think it would be a valuable asset to any M2 extension developer.

Answer (score 2):

Magento2 follows the PSR-2 coding standards.

So you can use PHPCS to scan for coding standard violations.

```
./vendor/bin/phpcs -n --standard="PSR2" ./app/code/<Vendor>/<ModuleName>/*
```

But magento has written its own custom rules over the PSR2 standards so you can try the following as well

```
./vendor/bin/phpcs --standard="./dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Php/_files/phpcs/" ./app/code/<Vendor>/<ModuleName>/*
```

Next if you looking for code audit tool you can use [Magento ECG](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/tree/master/EcgM2) for Magento2

Also for module verification there is a different [script available](https://gist.github.com/alankent/f9c1853715090dbdbc69#file-validate_m2_package-php) 
You can read the details [here](https://alankent.me/2016/02/01/magento-2-marketplace-upload-validation-tool-quick-note/)

Comment: It also adds some other standards :)

Comment: @OlaviSau you can have a look to the file `.php_cs` present in the root of the magento installation, it is the default PHPCS check hook that magento recommends to use.

Comment: @OlaviSau I have updated by answer please check if that helps .....

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for: https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard

This is an added ruleset for `PHP_CodeSniffer` with Magento ECG (Expert Consulting Group)'s additional standards. The github page includes full directions on installation and usage. If you use an IDE with PHPCS support (like PhpStorm), you can set it up to apply the `EcgM2` standard without much difficulty.

Note that the Marketplace code verification process does not exactly match the ECG ruleset (yet; they're working on that), and that it covers some things the ruleset couldn't possibly (like plagiarism).